# Firestore only show message from document

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to only show the message the user inputs from the document. The code to show the document is this:

```html
<v-list-item>
            <v-list-item v-for="message in task" v-bind:key="message"> 
      <v-chip color="primary" class="sent">{{message}}</v-chip>
    </v-list-item>

 <v-container class="messagebox">
      <v-row>
        <v-col cols="12">
          <v-text-field
            v-model="message"
            rounded
            filled
            outlined
            dense
            label="Message"
            append-icon="mdi-send-circle"
            @click:append="addTask"
          ></v-text-field>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
```

This gets the information from firebase, and this is the code I have to send the data to firebase

```js
<script>
import { db } from "@/main";
export default {
  data: () => ({
    message: null,
    task: []
  }),
  mounted() {
    this.getTask();
  },
  methods: {
    scrollToEnd() {
      var chatbox = document.querySelector("#chatbox");
      chatbox.scrollTop = chatbox.scrollHeight - chatbox.clientHeight;
    },
    async getTask() {
      let snapshot = await db.collection("test").get();
      let task = [];
      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        let appData = doc.get('message');
        task.push(appData);
      });
      this.task = task;
    },
  async addTask() {
    if (this.message != "") {
      await db.collection("test").add({
          message: this.message
        });
        this.getTask();
        this.message = "";
    }
  }
  }
};
</script>
```

However when i run my code, I get [ {"hi"}], instead of just "hi"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to change how you display the data in your view to:

```
<li v-for="msg in message">
  <v-chip color="primary" class="sent" style="display.block">{{ msg.message }}
</li>
```

Comment: I tried that, however it doesnt show anything when I put task.message. I was able to reduce it to just show the message, however it shows the whole array [{"hi}] instead of just the string "hi"

Comment: Ah, it's an array? I missed that. In that case, you'll need to have a list in the rendering code also: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html